# Antiguo corte de pelo "valcarra"

Tags: vocabulario, historia, palabras-raras

El tratamento de los nuevos soldados en California por 1820 era, según José María Amador, así:

> Después de filiado el recluta le hacían tupé y valcarra. El tupé era que le afeitaban toda la mitad del frente de la cabeza, dejándole sólo a los lados la valcarra que caía sobre la cara y servía de patilla. La parte de atrás formaba la coleta que era entrenzado. Esto era tan ridículo que nadie se prestó a ello por su voluntad. Todos los que sufrieron esa trasquila, fueron forzados. Esta ridícula invención fue obra del Gobr. Solá y del Capn. de la Guerra.

Aunque esa moda fuera única -- y yo no sé si era -- ¿la palabra "valcarra" sugiere algo sobre posibles orígenes de la costumbre? ¿Hay algo parecido,  más conocido en el idioma?

Se me occurre que posiblemente era semejante a lo que hacen en la Universidad de Chile a los estudiantes recién llegados, llamados "mechones". No tenían que afeitarse, por lo menos cuando anduve por allá, pero tal vez era diferente antes.

[ Para quien quiera leer la pregunta antecedente, en el inglés, está en: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/38091/ridiculous-military-haircut-in-spanish-california ]

> After being enlisted, the recruits were given a toupee [tupé] and a **valcarra**. The toupee was when the entire front half of the head was shaved, leaving only the valcarra on the sides. The **valcarra** would drop on the sides of the face and would serve as sideburns [patilla]. The hair behind the head [coleta] was braided into a pigtail [entrenzado]. This haircut was so ridiculous that no one would voluntarily accept it. Those who suffered this shearing were forced to have it. This ridiculous invention was the work of Governor Solá and Captain de la Guerra.

Comment: Hay aquí dos respuestas muy buenas. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 5):

Siguiendo el descubrimiento de @blonfu he llegado a un diccionario de "*Idiotismos Hispano-Mexicanos*" de Melchor Ocampo ([pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjWvfP63YHWAhUMS2MKHT7GBREQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdigital.dgb.uanl.mx%2Fla%2F1080042635_C%2F1080042635_T3%2F1080042635_MA.PDF&usg=AFQjCNE4y630FJn2r72OCZQHyzGXmV8NqQ) de 50M), escrito a mediados del siglo XIX, donde aparece la definición que buscas:

> **Balcarra**. — f. Mechón largo y de pelo que cuelga de las sienes cubriendo las orejas: este peinado es muy antiguo y hoy se conserva todavía entre muchos de nuestros indios. Porción larga y desordenada de cabellos, lanas ó pelos, que cuelga desairadamente. *Como borrega de diezmo con más balcarras que alientos*; fr. fam. que se dice de algunos que se hallan en la miseria, en gran necesidad.
>
> **Balcarriento, ta**.— adj. Lo que tiene balcarras.
>
> **Balcarrota**. — f. No es aumentativo, sino isos. de Balcarra.

Acerca del origen de la palabra no se dice nada, pero puedo aportar otras dos posibilidades, aparte de la "falcada" propuesta por walen.

- En Escocia hay (hubo?) una villa llamada Balcarres. La familia Balcarres está involucrada en la colonización de India y Norteamérica. Alexander y James Lindsay, padre e hijo, Condes de Balcarr**e**s fueron gobernadores de Jamaica. Alguno de ellos aparece mencionado en documentos relacionados con la independencia de México y California, como *Earl of Balcarr**a**s* (se reemplaza la "e" por "a"). También hay un Lord Balcarras involucrado en la historia de Cuba. ¿Puede haber una relación con el peinado de esta gente?
- En Cuba hay un Río Valcarras y una Sierra de Valcarras, cerca de la ciudad de Bayamo. Ahora el problema es saber por qué esos lugares tienen ese nombre. Tal vez porque en la zona habitaban unos hipotéticos *indios valcarras* (que se peinaban con valcarras), o porque el español que las bautizó provenía del pueblo de Valcarra, en Galicia, cosa que es probable pero que no tiene ninguna relación con el pelo.

En fin, son puras especulaciones.

Comment: Muy buen hallazgo ese diccionario. *Isos* es *igual* en griego (que cuadra con "no es aumentativo") pero como dices parece una abreviatura y no encuentro una palabra que encaje con eso.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que he encontrado algo. Si es un error de transcripción es muy posible que la palabra sea en realidad **balcarrias**.

Según la descripción del corte de pelo pensé que *valcarra* tenía que ser el pelo de los laterales de la cabeza y a partir de ahí encontré la palabra *balcarrotas* que coincidía con esa descripción. No lo encuentro en diccionarios aunque tampoco he hecho una búsqueda muy exhaustiva.

En [lexicoon.org](http://lexicoon.org/es/balcarrotas) *balcarrotas* me muestra varios textos interesantes:

> (..)físicos, los trajes nativos y las balcarrotas o estilo de peinado indígena, cualquiera de los cuales, o todos, podrían haberse aplicado igualmente a los mestizos.

Otro:

> (...) un hombre "trasquilado" del casquete y con dos 
>   mechones que caen en espiral desde la sien llamados "balcarrotas", (...)

Hay varios más del estilo pero el siguiente es el que me interesa:

> (...) y sobre las orejas dos mechones largos que le llegaban casi hasta los hombros, según la moda de todos ellos, y que llamaban de balcarrotas o balcarrias.

Entonces tenemos que *balcarrias* es sinónimo de *balcarrotas* y es muy similar a *valcarra* del que no hay apenas referencias aparte de este texto de la pregunta.

---

**Actualización:**

Con la respuesta de @Rodrigo queda claro que *balcarras* y *balcarrotas* son sinónimos, de la primera hay poquísimas referencias pero puede perfectamente ser derivada de la segunda, la raíz es la misma.

De *balcarrotas* podemos encontrar más información, en México eran mechones de pelo que cuelgan a los lados de la cabeza pero en Colombia llamaban así a las patillas. La acepción colombiana es lo que en inglés llaman *[sideburns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideburns)*, en la entrada de la wikipedia sobre está palabra leemos:

> (...) as well as Colombians, who wear their sideburns long and
>   typically do not have any other facial hair, are said to be wearing
>   "**balcarrotas**" (...)

Balcarrotas según la acepción colombiana:

[image: Hombre con balcarrotas]

Se supone que los los indios mexicanos se rapaban la cabeza y se dejaban las balcarrotas a los lados según dicen en varios diccionarios o textos que hablan de ello pero no encuentro imágenes con ese corte de pelo, ninguna foto o dibujo de indios mexicanos muestra ese peculiar peinado.

Todavía no he encontrado naba sobre la etimología.

Comment: @walen Yo diría que *valcarra* es un error o una mala pronunciación, hay muy pocas referencias y la diferencia con *balcarria* es mínima.

Comment: Hay cierta conexión. "la valcarra ... servía de patilla."

Answer (score 2):

La palabra "valcarra" no aparece en el diccionario de la RAE.
Tampoco aparece en el CORDE, que recoge miles de textos en español de los últimos 1000 y pico años.
<strike>Ni siquiera Google ofrece resultados que tengan que ver con un corte de pelo.

**A todas luces, la palabra "valcarra" no existe**.</strike>
[Rodrigo ha encontrado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21924/antiguo-corte-de-pelo-valcarra#comment34675_21926) algunas referencias por internet; todas indican que viene a ser un sinónimo de "mechones", "greñas", "pelo largo"... pero ninguna da pistas del origen.

Se me ocurre que **quizá es una <strike>mala transcripción</strike> evolución de otra palabra**.

Una candidata sería "**[falcada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HW98jY9)**", que en Argentina quiere decir "manojo de hierba que se puede coger con la mano".
Si he entendido bien la descripción del corte de pelo, lo que se hacía era afeitarles la cabeza sólo por arriba, dejando pelo colgando a los lados y atrás. Quizá estos mechones de pelo laterales parecían "manojos de hierba" y por eso se les llamó *falcada*, y de ahí se llegó a "valcarra".

O puede que, dado que el [Gobernador Solá](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pablo_Vicente_de_Sol%C3%A1) era de origen vasco, y siendo él quien introdujo ese corte de pelo, a lo mejor es una antigua palabra vasca que ya ha desaparecido.

Comment: Tampoco yo encontré nada. Sin embargo, buscando sí encontré el libro y [el fragmento](https://books.google.es/books?id=Fk5oVvisLVIC&lpg=PA37&ots=TyS-UWLoM7&dq=%22valcarra%22&hl=es&pg=PA37#v=onepage&q=%22valcarra%22&f=false), donde repite la palabra _valcarra_ tres veces como mínimo.

Comment: La descripción es cuanto menos rara: _El tupé era que le afeitaban toda la mitad del frente de la cabeza, dejándole sólo a los lados la valcarra que caía sobre la cara y servía de patilla._. Inicialmente pensé en la [tonsura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonsura) pero no. Una patilla que cae sobre la cara no me cuadra, pero definitivamente esto tiene pinta de... ¡macarra!

Comment: @walen Mira [este enlace](https://www.uv.mx/bnotarial/detalles.aspx?idA=1_1798_15945&indice=Te&letra=O) y [este otro](http://elbasofias.blogspot.cl/). Mencionan las "valcarras" refiriéndose al pelo. Puede que no sea una mala transcripción.

Comment: Ya [aquí](https://twitter.com/maperez324/status/261973114089508864) alguien dice que significa "greñas".

Comment: "la maldita valcarra en el pelo es lo de hoy" -- perfecto, gracias @Rodrigo por eso.