# Origen de llamar a los nuevos universitarios "mechones"

Tags: vocabulario, palabras-raras, chile

Según lo que tengo entendido, un mechón común y corriente es una parte del cabello que se agarra para cortarse o colorearse.

[image]

En Chile, y no sé si en otros lugares, [se usa la palabra "mechón" para quien se matricula en un curso universitario](http://www.icei.uchile.cl/noticias/132491/admision-y-caracterizacion-de-estudiantes-nuevos-mechones-2017), y el ritual de desafiar físicamente a los nuevos estudiantes es el "mechoneo":

[image]

**¿Por qué?** Un mechón del cabello no parece tener que ver con los jóvenes aquellos, si no sea el caso que antiguamente [se obligaban a sufrir un corte de pelo humillante](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21924/antiguo-corte-de-pelo-valcarra).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agrego la explicación larga por si alguien no acaba de comprender la autorespuesta de Aaron, que es la correcta.

Una *mecha* es una "cuerda" o "tira". Parece que proviene del francés antiguo *mèche*, que significa lo mismo. Por ejemplo se llama *mecha* la cuerda de algodón que va dentro de las velas y de los cartuchos de dinamita, a cuya punta se prende fuego.

Si tienes un grupo de mechas y las separas en otro grupo más pequeño, obtienes un *mechón*.

Como un cabello es similar a una cuerda (o mejor dicho es un tipo de cuerda), podemos hablar de una mecha o mechón de pelo. Esta metáfora está recogida en el diccionario de la RAE.

Las mechas y mechones con el significado de "pelos" están abundantemente presentes en el **habla chilena tradicional**. Algunos ejemplos:

> **mechonear**: tirarle el pelo a alguien. Sobre todo hablando de peleas entre mujeres o cuando un padre amonesta a su hijo.
>
> **irse a las mechas**: pasar de la discusión a los golpes.
>
> esto es **tirado de las mechas**: es absurdo.
>
> es un **mechas tiesas** (o tiene las mechas tiesas): tiene el pelo grueso, o es de condición humilde, o es terco.

Como puedes ver, *mechonear* ya existía antes con el significado de "tirar el pelo" (esto aparece por lo menos en un diccionario de modismos de 1875). Entonces, cuando apareció el concepto de *mechón* como "**estudiante de primer año de la universidad**", el uso de la familia de palabras mech- ya estaba bien asentado. A los alumnos recién ingresados a la universidad, como parte de la novatada, se les cortaba el pelo, y por sinécdoque se les empezó a llamar los *mechones*. La ceremonia se llamó *mechoneo*.

Explico todo esto para que quede claro que en el origen hubo un juego de palabras que involucraba, además del corte de mechas, el ser "vapuleado". La primera referencia a esta tradición que encuentro buscando en la Internet es de la Universidad de Concepción en 1955. Actualmente la ceremonia de mechoneo no es ni muy ceremoniosa ni involucra las mechas de pelo.

Desconozco si en los demás países es frecuente el uso de mechas para hablar de pelo, aunque sé que actualmente se refiere sobre todo a un estilo de teñido capilar por secciones.

Comment: Son buenos datos. Lo único que me queda por saber es como era la trasquila de los mechones. ¿La persona se afeitaba, o todo el cabello le quedaba corto, o el corte seguía algún padrón aún más extraño y humillante?

Comment: Se cortaba desordenadamente un mechón de pelo, de modo que el joven quedara feo.

Comment: La foto que tú muestras es del mechoneo actual, que no tiene nada que ver con el original. Lamentablemente no pude encontrar ninguna foto del mechoneo antiguo.

Comment: En España hasta donde yo sé solo se usa *mecha* para el  pelo hablando de mechones de pelo teñido: *tener mechas*, *hacerse mechas*. Un grupo de pelos es un mechón, aparte de eso no he oído usar otras variantes como *mechonear* o expesiones con la palabra *mecha*.

Comment: Rodrigo, ¿cómo sabemos que el acto era quitarle un mechón de pelo, y no separar o definir uno o más mechones? Ud. recordará que la "valcarra" dejaba al novato tres nuevos mechones (aunque cabe notar que los californios lucían cabellos largos). sí noto que el texto de WP lo llama "el corte de un mechón".

Comment: No tengo ninguna fuente que pueda especificar lo que hacían con el pelo, lo lamento.

Answer (score 2):

Ups. Acabé de encontrar la respuesta en [el articulo "Novatada" de  Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novatada):

> El nombre de origen se debe a que la tradición incluía el corte de un mechón de cabello que marcaba al alumno debutante.