# Significado de la antigua abreviatura "isos."

Tags: palabras-raras, abreviaturas

Para responder [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21924/6915) descargué un libro mexicano de mediados del siglo XIX en el que aparece con frecuencia la abreviatura "isos.". Por contexto se puede deducir que se refiere a un *sinónimo*, o a algo similar.

¿Alguien conoce la palabra o frase expandida que corresponde a "isos." y su significado preciso?

La pueden ver en uso en el siguiente recorte, en las entradas de las palabras *Bachicha* y *Balcarrota*.

[image: recorte texto mexicano del siglo XIX donde se usa la abreviatura "isos."]

Comment: Do you think it might come from the Latin _ipse_ (or in this case _ipsos_) which means the same? I suppose _mismo_ may have the same root.

Comment: Lo que primero me llegó a la menta fue «isónimo», pero explicaría solo una, y no dos, de las eses.

Comment: No parece que se utilice en otros diccionarios, tampoco en otro tipo de textos, al menos no he podido encontrar nada. He descubierto la palabra *isónimo* y veo que @guifa ya la conocía pero nos falta la *s* final.

Comment: Viendo los usos de isos [en el texto](https://books.google.com/books?id=DI3tl5EbjJ4C&pg=RA2-PA130&lpg=RA2-PA130&dq=no+es+aumentativo+si+no+isos&source=bl&ots=wJvHOegUfX&sig=HxgDnAci2RIXWZwbfVbd-kD00vE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvs57FuoTWAhVszIMKHdJcB94Q6AEIQDAI#v=onepage&q=isos&f=false) (especialmente para _arete_ y _frijol_) sí que parece tener el sentido de "sinónimo". El libro no parece tener un apéndice donde explique esta abreviatura

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pues hete aquí que hay que ir a otra obra del autor del libro para saber su significado. En las [*Obras Completas de D. Melchor Ocampo*](https://books.google.es/books?id=KQ8wAAAAYAAJ&q=%22isos%5C.%22%20abreviatura%20etimologia&dq=%22isos%5C.%22%20abreviatura%20etimologia&hl=es&sa=X&redir_esc=y) vemos:

[image]

Es decir:

> *Isos.* es abreviatura de *isosónima*, neologismo usado por Ocampo, igual o equivalente a...

Y no consigo ver nada más :/ Estoy analizando ahora [otras referencias](https://www.google.es/search?tbm=bks&hl=es&q=isos%C3%B3nima%20ocampo) y todas dan con Ocampo. Muchas de las obras apenas están escaneadas y no hay demasiados fragmentos. Lo que más y mejor encuentro es una cita de [*De historiografía lingüística e historia de las lenguas*](https://books.google.es/books?id=j5Bnb5Jh1rcC) en la página 212:

> Ocampo consideró que un buen número de palabras y expresiones de México eran "isosónimas" de las peninsulares, tomando en cuenta las connotaciones diacrónicas y diatópicas de la categoría del dialecto.

Esto hace pensar que *isosónima* sería una palabra compuesta por *isos* y *sinónima*, refiriéndose a sinónimos entre zonas de habla hispana. Habría que empaparse bien en las teorías de Ocampo para conseguir el significado exacto de este término. Dejémoslo para un día en el que tengamos tiempo y ganas :)

Eso sí, *isosonima* no aparece en ningún otro lugar, luego es un neologismo que no parece que tuviera continuidad.

Comment: Ese @fedorqui! Mira que he repasado los libros de ese señor  buscando algo así y nada. No sé como has encontrado eso. Fantástico! Duda resuelta.

Comment: @blonfu el problema está en que "isos" Google lo asocia con las certificaciones ISO y los resultados tienen mucha morralla. El punto no sé si lo considera expresión regular, pero por si acaso busquè "isos\. abreviatura etimología" y se hizo la luz.

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente. Ahora me da un poco de culpabilidad notar que hubo mucho esfuerzo de parte de muchos amigos, para encontrar una palabra inventada por una sola persona y que ha sido usada solo por esa misma persona.

Comment: Fedorqui [idiotismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Kud9QoP) no es cosa suya, existe en lingüística.

Comment: @blonfu ¡gracias! Elimino la referencia.

Comment: @Rodrigo faltaría más. Ocampo estará contento de que cien años después se haya popularizado su concepto :)

Comment: La frase que sigue el texto arriba más explica el proyecto de él: "... [Ocampo] aceptaba la existencia de pronunciaciones y construcciones viciosas en el dialecto mexicano."

Answer (score 0):

**[ISO](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?iso)** = Igual

> La voz de origen griego, ISO, significa "igual". No es una palabra
>   castellana. Es un elemento radican que nos viene del griego y es usado
>   en palabras compuestas como:
>
> - isómetro
> - [isósceles](http://dle.rae.es/?id=abeu2lU) (triángulo) : *triángulo que tiene iguales solamente dos ángulos y dos lados*
> - [isótopo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MCfkts6): *Cada uno de los elementos químicos que poseen el mismo número de protones y distinto número de neutrones*

En la RAE encontramos el término defino como:

> [ISO](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MBPWPlj) = Igual 
>   *Del gr. ἰσο- iso-.* Otros ejemplos son:
>
> - [Isomorfo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MCIC8ob): "*Dicho de dos o más cuerpos: Que, con diferente composición química, presentan igual estructura cristalina y pueden cristalizar asociados* "
> - [Isofonía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MBnlVkC): "*Igualdad de sonoridad.*"

La RAE define así [sinónimo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XzADiyT):

> Dicho de una palabra o de una expresión: Que, respecto de otra, tiene
>   el mismo significado o muy parecido, como empezar y comenzar

Comment: Isos significa iguales

Comment: Pero entonces había problemas de concordancia, porque dice "es más usado **su** isos".

Comment: "Es mas usado su igual". La diferencia entre igual y sinónimo es que uno dice que tiene es igual y otro que tiene el mismo significado.

Comment: @Rodrigo Creo que *isos* puede ser igual o iguales (por lo que he visto ya que no sé nada de griego), lo comenté en la pregunta donde surgió esta duda. Pero usar esa  palabra en griego es raro y además está el  punto, lo que hace pensar que es una abreviatura y no una palabra completa.